# Django: How to define a ForeignKey to User OR to another model?

Tags: django

I'm building a site for people doing maintenance tasks in properties. The user can have clients and can perform maintenance tasks both in his properties and in his client's properties. How can I define the ownership of the property to be User OR Client?

My models should be something like this:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Property(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=100)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User OR Client)

class MaintenanceTask(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=100)
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property)
```

Obvliously, `owner = models.ForeignKey(User OR Client)` is not correct. How can I solve this problem?

And the general question:
**How can I define a ForeignKey to User OR to another model?**

Comment: You need to use a [`Generic Foreign Key`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Generic Relation and more precisely GenericForeignKey. You can have a look at GenericForeignKey in [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations)

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class TaggedItem(models.Model):
    content_type= models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to it. You had forgotten to include the `object_id` field to store the actual object id.  Fixed it for you.

Comment: @Jamie Cockburn, yes you're right, I forgot it. Thanks a lot for the update!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is a GenericForeignKey, as the other answer pointed. However, I was missing an example to understand it.

In the following post there is a very good example and a way to use GenericForeignKey As Single Form Field:
http://adamalton.blogspot.com.es/2014/02/displaying-django-genericforeignkey-as.html